# python list comprehension with tuples (nested list)

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, tokenize, sentence, paragraphs

I am working on the following list comprehension which is supposed to convert a list of (document, category) tuples into a (list of paragraphs), category) tuples into ((list of sentences), (list of sentences), category) tuples.

Each (document, category) tuple is being split into (paragraph-list), category) tuple and then that goes 4 levels deep (document -> paragraphs -> sentences -> words).

Spyder says it has a syntax error. Any help please?

Ultimately the idea is to break documents into paragraphs into sentences
into words in the following hierarchy:
Doc-List

(Doc1, cat), (Doc2, cat), (Doc3, cat)
(doc1sent1, doc1sent2, doc1sent3), cat)
((sent1word1, sent1word2, sent1word3), (sent2word1, sent2word2), cat) ...

```
self._PSW =       
[[list(self.ConvertOneDoc(paragraph, "Sents")     
for paragraph in [list((self.ConvertOneDoc(document, "Para"), category))    
for document, category in self._CatDocs]]
```

Comment: Please read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Assuming that you have some function `f(document) = paragraphs` that converts documents to paragraphs `[(list(f(document)), category) for document, category in self._CatDocs]` should be sufficent.

Comment: Thank you. Your response is actually the inner part which I already have and which works great:

[list((self.ConvertOneDoc(document, TBD), category)) for document, category in self._CatDocs]

Where TBD can be Paragraphs, Sentences or Words

Comment: The link that @Cleb suggested contains the following: '"It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.'.  Please clarify exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It has a syntax error.
@Cleb seems to have deleted his comment.

Comment: The general advice is that list comprehensions are for simple loops. If it looks too big and complicated then use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: I'm seeing three opening '[' and only two closing ']'. Fix that and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'm still trying to get it to work. I took out the extra "[" as you pointed out, leaving:

    self._ProcessedDocuments = [list(self.ConvertOneDoc(paragraph, "Sents") for paragraph in [list((self.ConvertOneDoc(document, "Para"), category)) for document, category in self._CatDocs]]

 but when it runs it creates:
"NoneType object of builtins module"

Answer (score 0):

Abit late, but an answer...

You miss one parenthese to close the first list `list(...)̀  and you have one opening square bracket in excess. Try:

```
self._PSW = [
    list(self.ConvertOneDoc(paragraph, "Sents"))     
    for paragraph in [
            list((self.ConvertOneDoc(document, "Para"), category))    
            for document, category in self._CatDocs
        ]
    ]
```

Now, your code is a bit obscure, but your intention seems clear. As I 
understood, you want something nested like, per document: 
`([[words]], category)` (`words` is a sentence, `[words]` a paragraph 
and `[[words]]` a document). Here's a try to fix it:

```
self._PSW = [
    ([
        [
            self.ConvertOneDoc(sentence, "Word") 
            for sentence in self.ConvertOneDoc(paragraph, "Sent")
        ]
        for paragraph in self.ConvertOneDoc(document, "Para") 
    ], category)
    for document, category in self._CatDocs
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I went a different route and I have touched list comprehension in a little  bit. But thanks!!